# Substitution Table in TKIP

Tags: encryption, cryptography, wpa-enterprise

In TKIP Encapsulation, we divided the per packet key mixing process into two phases.

In phase 1, we are taking three inputs i.e temporal key (128-bit session key), transmitter MAC address (48 bits) and first 32 bits of the TSC (sequence number, 48 bits) and giving an 80 bit key (TTAK) as output.

In phase 2, we take TTAK, temporal key and last 16 bits of TSC. It gives as output a 128 bit key which we further use for WEP encapsulation.

But, in both phases, they are talking about a Substitution Table or S-BOX. In the following link, they have given some info about it, but still I am not understanding how to form a Substitution Table, or is it some kind of standard table?

http://etutorials.org/Networking/802.11+security.+wi-fi+protected+access+and+802.11i/Part+II+The+Design+of+Wi-Fi+Security/Chapter+11.+TKIP/Per-Packet+Key+Mixing_1pzq9/